# PowerBI - Web Scraping more than a million pages

Tags: web-scraping, powerbi

I want to pull Agent/Broker name, license # and expiry date from http://mbsweblist.fsco.gov.on.ca/ShowLicence.aspx?M13000248~

The numerical value after 'M' is the license number. 
I have the power query to pull the data for a couple of licenses. How do I pull the data for list = {00000000..99999999} ?. Isn't PowerBI suitable for this purpose?. Any other method?

Thank you , appreciate your help.

```
(page as number) as table =>
let
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://mbsweblist.fsco.gov.on.ca/ShowLicence.aspx?M"&Number.ToText(page)&"~")),
Data1 = Source{1}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data1,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Column1] = "Agent/Broker Name:" or [Column1] = "Expiry Date:" or [Column1] = "Licence #:"))
in
#"Filtered Rows"



let
Source = {18001928,13000248},
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Page"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each GetData([Page])),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Custom.Column1", "Custom.Column2"})
in
#"Expanded Custom"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: I'd advise caution if trying to scrape "more than a million pages" - it's pretty certain the web server would see the repeated requests as a breach of their terms of service / some form of attack.

However, to answer the question from a technical capability perspective - You're nearly right with your approach of listing the licence numbers, then passing the licence number to a function to get the web data. Your exection isn't quite right, though.

Step 1: create a function which extracts the data you want, in the format you want, for one single URL - generated by passing a licence number as a parameter. I named this function WebData:

```
(LicenceNumber) =>
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://mbsweblist.fsco.gov.on.ca/ShowLicence.aspx?M" & Number.ToText(LicenceNumber) & "~")),
    WebData = Source{1}[Data],
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(WebData, {{"Column1", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ":"), type text}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter",1),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Top Rows"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

Now create a second query which lists the licence numbers for which you wish to retrieve data, then uses the WebData function to retrieve each page data, and finally combines that data into a table:

```
let
    Source = {13000246..13000250},
    #"Convert to Table" = Table.FromList(Source,Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Licence Number"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Convert to Table",{{"Licence Number", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Get WebData" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "WebData", each try WebData([Licence Number]) otherwise #table({},{})),
    #"Combine WebData" = Table.Combine(#"Get WebData"[WebData]),
    #"Changed Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Combine WebData",{{"Agent/Broker Name", type text}, {"Licence #", type text}, {"Brokerage Name", type text}, {"Licence Class", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Issue Date", type date}, {"Expiry Date", type date}, {"Inactive Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Types"
```

Note the start and end values of the Source line determine the range of the list used.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to retrieve data for a range {13000000..13009999}. Error - "An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation."

Comment: It may be that when it searches for a invalid/non-existing license the tool is throwing error. Is there a work around for this?.

Comment: Thank you for your response Olly, but now the entire query is throwing an error if a matching license is not found. "Expression.Error: The column 'Agent/Broker Name' of the table wasn't found.
Details:Agent/Broker Name" . For eg: if we search using {13009995..13009999},

Comment: Are you stepping through this, and trying to modify this to suit, at all, or are you asking me to do it all? I've demonstrated a technique for error handling, which you could easily use to modify the final "Changed Types" step, where the error is happening (because those licence numbers return no data)...